# Internal Server Error при редиректе

Tags: .htaccess, apache

Содержимое файла .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

При попытке загрузить даже просто localhost выдает "500 Internal Server Error".

В логах ошибка:

```
/var/www/html/.htaccess: Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps 
misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
```

Answer (score 1):

вероятнее всего, в конфигурации *apache* отключен модуль *rewrite*.

в *debian-основных* дистрибутивах современных версий (*ubuntu*, *mint* и т.п.) включить модуль можно такой командой:

```
$ sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

после этого надо перезапустить *apache*.

---

также стоит убедиться, что в конфигурации *virtualhost*, внутри нужного *location-а* директиве *allowoverride* присвоено значение *all*. примерно так

```
<virtualhost ...>
  <location ...>
    ...
    allowoverride all
    ...
   </location>
</virtualhost>
```