# Как перенаправить с new.php на new?

Tags: .htaccess

`site.com/new.php` смотрится не так красиво, как `site.com/new`

Такое правило не хочет работать

```
RewriteRule ^new$ new.php [L,QSA]
```

UPD:

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://site.com/error.php

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^new new.php [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/page/1$
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://site.com/? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/app/page/1$
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://site.com/app? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/game/page/1$
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://site.com/game? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ error.php [L,QSA]
```

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/435956/178576 // ну, и про `rewriteengine on` не стоит забывать.

Comment: он включен) просто его не вписал

Comment: значит, вероятно, вы не вписали и других правил, которые могут препятствовать работе упомянутого.

Comment: @emtecif: Исходя из вашего полного `.htaccess`, мой ответ был не в кассу, удалил его.

Comment: И так, что же делать?

Comment: @emtecif: Почитал вот это: http://habrahabr.ru/company/sprinthost/blog/129560/ Там пишется: mod_rewrite запускает обработку запроса снова и снова, до тех пор, пока он не перестанет меняться. И флаг [L] не может это остановить.

Comment: @emtecif: Давайте попробуем проверить, не проваливаемся ли мы в эту проблему. Поменяйте последнее правило на `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ test.php [L,QSA]` и посмотрите, выдаётся ли по `site.com/new` реально `test.php`.

Comment: `error.php` выдает

Comment: @emtecif: А вы не забыли положить файл `test.php`? (и `new.php` тоже).

Comment: Вот блин, забыл)) работает теперь, но, после `new` можно писать что угодно, т.е. `/new` и `/new46784vds` одно и то же, и ошибки здесь нет

Comment: верните `$` в `rewriterule` и будет выдавать `new.php` только для *url* `new`.

Comment: perfect, идеально) @VladD, напишите полный ответ ниже

Comment: Ну, весь ответ получается только «проверьте, есть ли `new.php`» (если я правильно понимаю, что вы сделали). Или вы ещё убрали последнее правило?

Comment: @VladD, по-моему, у автора не было как раз `new.php`.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin: тьфу, очепятка

Comment: напишите в чем была проблема и т.д, √ заслужили

Comment: @emtecif: Стыдно признаться, но я всё ещё не понимаю, почему у вас работает несмотря на наличие последней строки. Если пост с хабра не врёт и набор правил реально применяется много раз до тех пор, пока есть изменения, при второй итерации мы должны проваливаться в последнее правило, разве нет?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin: Может, у вас есть идея по поводу предыдущего комментария?

Comment: признаюсь, я выставил не полный файл `.htaccess`, но то что не выставил вряд ли важно)

Comment: @VladD, в правиле по поводу `new` стоит опция `[l]` (*last*), т.е., если правило «срабатывает», дальнейшие правила не просматриваются.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin: Я ссылался в 6-м комментарии сверху на статью на хабре, она утверждает, что если в результате пробега правил адрес поменялся, то весь набор запускается снова. Таким образом у нас должно получиться так: (1-ый пробег) сработало правило `^new$`, [L] -> итерация окончена, строка поменялась. (2-й пробег) правило `^new$` не матчится, но матчится последнее правило -> test.php. (3-й пробег) опять работает только последнее правило -> test.php, результат не поменялся, конец. Верно?

Comment: @VladD, да, действительно: чтобы правило срабатывало на `/new`, и не срабатывло на `/newblabla`, то, ввиду наличия последней строки, надо больше точности: `rewriterule ^new(\.php)?$ new.php [l,qsa]`.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin: Внесу в ответ, спасибо!

Comment: @alexanderbarakin: Думаю, как бы сделать так, чтобы при этом выдать 404 на `new.php`...

Comment: @VladD, вероятно, надо анализировать `THE_REQUEST,`. в статье есть пример.

Comment: @VladD, а зачем вообще выдавать ошибку на запрос `/new.php`?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin: Ну, чтобы скрыть, что за сценой на деле `.php`. Негоже показывать юзерам «грязное бельё» имплементации // По поводу `THE_REQUEST`, мне показалось, что `REQUEST_URI` проще. Там будет только `/new`, без всего остального (если верить [документации](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как указал ТС, `site.com/new` выводит на страницу 404. Если правило работает, и `new` перенаправляется на `new.php`, самая простая возможная причина — отсутствие самого файла `new.php`.

Затем, как верно подсказал @alexander barakin, в правиле «потерялся» завершающий `$`, в результате не только `site.com/new`, но и `site.com/newwhatever` приводило на `new.php`.

---

Обновление: согласно [этой статье](http://habrahabr.ru/company/sprinthost/blog/129560/), если после применения набора правил адрес изменяется, то правила запускаются снова (возможно, в новом каталоге) до тех пор, пока будут изменения.

Учитывая, что последнее правило в списке заменяет всё на страницу ошибки, это может привести к проблеме. В этом случае первый пробег заменит `new` на `new.php`, но во время второго пробега сработает лишь последнее правило, и заменит `new.php` на `error.php`.

Таким образом, возможно, необходимо после правила

```
RewriteRule ^new$ new.php [L,QSA]
```

добавить

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/new$
RewriteRule ^new.php$ new.php [L,QSA]
```

Это правило сработает во второй раз, завершит обработку правил (`[L]`) и не даст сработать финальному правилу. `RewriteCond` нужно, чтобы правило не срабатывало на введённом в браузере `new.php`.